# Where can i upload the pickle file on the webserver as when i upload the. pkl file in main directory it shows no file name or directory clf. Pkl

Tags: python, flask, pickle, digital-ocean

I am trying to deploy a machine learning model  on a web server of digital ocean which predict the probability of disease based on its symptoms. 
For this i am using ubuntu 18.04 console and flask.
My working directory is

```
var/www/na/na
```

All the files are uploaded in above directory.Content of directory will be posted below. 
Everything works fine i successfully hosted my website. 
This is my flask code

```
from flask import Flask,request,render_template,redirect,url_for,session,logging,flash
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://root:@localhost/naksh_main'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
# creating content in database
class Naksh_main_tb(db.Model):
    sno = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    datetime = db.Column(db.String(12), unique=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/register',methods=['GET','POST'])
def register():
    if(request.method=='POST'):
        "fetch entry from database"
        # u name is just a variable which is storing name content of form
        uname=request.form.get('uname')
        passw=request.form.get('passw')

        existing_entry=Naksh_main_tb.query.filter_by(email=uname).first()
        if existing_entry:
            flash('Email already exist')
            return redirect(url_for("register"))
        # to add entry
        # email from database will store uname variable and password from database will store passw variable
        new_entry=Naksh_main_tb(email=uname,password=passw)
        db.session.add(new_entry)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for("login"))
    return render_template("register.html")

@app.route('/login',methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():
    if(request.method=='POST'):
        "fetch entry from database"
        louname=request.form.get('uname')
        lopassw=request.form.get('passw')
        login=Naksh_main_tb.query.filter_by(email=louname,password=lopassw).first()
        if login is not None:
            # flash('pleas check')
            return render_template('nakshoverview.html')


        # else:
        #     return redirect(url_for("login"))
    return render_template("login.html")

@app.route('/',methods=["GET","POST"])
def hello_world():
    if request.method == "POST":
        print(request.form)
        # mydict will access the form using name
        mydict=request.form
        fever=int(mydict['fever'])
        pain=int(mydict['pain'])
        runnynose=int(mydict['runnynose'])
        diffbreath=int(mydict['diffbreath'])



        # now here we can use names like fever pain inplace of values
        probability=mp.predict_proba([[fever,pain,age,runnynose,diffbreath]])
        # model.predictproba is used to predict probability

        prob=probability[0][1]
        # to select the probabilty using index 1
        print(prob)
        #this will return inf value and display it in show.html
        # return redirect(url_for('index'))
        return render_template('show.html',inf=round(prob*100))
    return render_template('index.html')


if __name__== "__init__":
    db.create_all()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Above code works fine
But when i try to deploy my machine learning model which is saved using a pickle file it throws an error. 
Problem occurs when i try to open clf. pkl file

```
from flask import Flask,request,render_template,redirect,url_for,session,logging,flash
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()

app = Flask(__name__)
import pickle

# open a file, where you stored the pickled data
file = open('model.pkl', 'rb')

# dump load model information to that file
mp = pickle.load(file)

# close the file
file.close()


app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://root:@localhost/naksh_main'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
# creating content in database
class Naksh_main_tb(db.Model):
    sno = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    datetime = db.Column(db.String(12), unique=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/register',methods=['GET','POST'])
def register():
    if(request.method=='POST'):
        "fetch entry from database"
        # u name is just a variable which is storing name content of form
        uname=request.form.get('uname')
        passw=request.form.get('passw')

        existing_entry=Naksh_main_tb.query.filter_by(email=uname).first()
        if existing_entry:
            flash('Email already exist')
            return redirect(url_for("register"))
        # to add entry
        # email from database will store uname variable and password from database will store passw variable
        new_entry=Naksh_main_tb(email=uname,password=passw)
        db.session.add(new_entry)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for("login"))
    return render_template("register.html")

@app.route('/login',methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():
    if(request.method=='POST'):
        "fetch entry from database"
        louname=request.form.get('uname')
        lopassw=request.form.get('passw')
        login=Naksh_main_tb.query.filter_by(email=louname,password=lopassw).first()
        if login is not None:
            # flash('pleas check')
            return render_template('nakshoverview.html')


        # else:
        #     return redirect(url_for("login"))
    return render_template("login.html")

@app.route('/',methods=["GET","POST"])
def hello_world():
    if request.method == "POST":
        print(request.form)
        # mydict will access the form using name
        mydict=request.form
        fever=int(mydict['fever'])
        pain=int(mydict['pain'])
        runnynose=int(mydict['runnynose'])
        diffbreath=int(mydict['diffbreath'])



        # now here we can use names like fever pain inplace of values
        probability=mp.predict_proba([[fever,pain,age,runnynose,diffbreath]])


        prob=probability[0][1]
        # to select the probabilty using index 1
        print(prob)
        #this will return inf value and display it in show.html
        # return redirect(url_for('index'))
        return render_template('show.html',inf=round(prob*100))
    return render_template('index.html')


if __name__== "__init__":
    db.create_all()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This error is thrown

```
[wsgi:error] mod_wsgi (pid=2228): Target WSGI script '/var/www/na/na.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module., referer: http://161.35.14.65/
[wsgi:error]mod_wsgi (pid=2228): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/na/na.wsgi'., referer: http://161.35.14.65/
[wsgi:error]Traceback (most recent call last):, referer: http://161.35.14.65/
[wsgi:error] File "/var/www/na/na.wsgi", line 7, in <module>, referer: http://161.35.14.65/
[wsgi:error]from na import app as application, referer: http://161.35.14.65/
[wsgi:error]File "/var/www/na/na/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>, referer: http://161.35.14.65/
[wsgi:error]file = open('model.pkl', 'rb'), referer: http://161.35.14.65/
[wsgi:error] [pid 2228]FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'model.pkl', referer: http://161.35.14.65/
```

My wsgi file is saved as na. wsgi in directory

```
var/www/na
```

Code for wsgi is

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/na/")

from na import app as application
application.secret_key = 'Add-secret'
```

When i run this code using python3 na.py it creates an model. pkl file but i am not able to load this file in my `__init__.py`

[image]

This  is the output if i don't try to load pickle file
[image]

Comment: Try to reduce the amount of details in your post and concentrate on the issue: `FileNotFoundError`. For example the machine learning code isn't needed for this issue. Only post relevent sections of your webapp code. For the exception log superfluous details like datetime, PID, client make it hard to read.

Comment: Okay sir. Thanks for telling

Comment: Did you try to use `file = open('na/model.pkl', 'rb')`? If that does not work, print the current directory before opening the file with `os.getcwd()`.

Comment: Okay i tried that at starting my server was loading for infinite time but after few attempts i got the output finally..thanks a lot